# AWS Athena SQL query for ELB access logs sort asc/desc by count of client:port with certain status code reply

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

For AWS ALB access logs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-access-logs.html), I would like an Athena SQL query example to sort descending/ascending by the count of the client:port field for elb_status_code/target_status_code during a start and end date (DD-MM-YYYY HH-MM).
The result of the query for target_status_code=500 to be like:

| client:port | count of target_status_code=500 |
| --- | --- |
| 70.132.2.XX:port | 2570 |
| 70.132.2.XX:port | 2315 |
| 80.122.1.XX:port | 1750 |
| ... | ... |

The point would be to find the top clients:port (The IP address and port of the requesting client) with the elb_status_code/target_status_code=4xx or 5xx (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the table described in [Querying Classic Load Balancer Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/elasticloadbalancer-classic-logs.html) , assuming you partition it by date (the partition key is called `date_partition_key` below), you could do something like this:

```sql
SELECT
  CONCAT(request_ip, ':', CAST(request_port AS VARCHAR)) AS client_port,
  COUNT(*) AS count_of_status_500
FROM elb_logs
WHERE elb_response_code = '500'
AND date_partition_key BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-01-03'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

The 1 and 2 in the group and order by clauses refer back to the first and second items in the select list, i.e. the client port and the count, respectively. It's just a convenient way of not having to repeat the function calls etc.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I found this link
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/athena-analyze-access-logs/
with some ALB access logs queries examples. This may be useful for users not very familiar with SQL queries (like me).